# Book that includes data in a cloud around shoppers at a mall in one scene

Tags: story-identification, novel

A science fiction book that I read in the last year (2015-2016), which had the protagonist lured to a shopping mall. The other person hit a button on his device and suddenly the protagonist could see all the data collected about each shopper in a cloud around that person. As the shopper passed through the mall, ads popped up keyed to his data.

Answer (score 2):

You might be referring to *[City of Paradigm](http://siliconangle.com/city-of-paradigm/)*. It's a 2015 novel about near-future technology and [it's got a scene at a shopping mall](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2015/08/18/city-of-paradigm-the-blockchain-and-the-retail-chain/) that includes keyed ads, although the context of user data is different.

> Bell sniffed at that and shrugged. “Yeah,” she said trying to sound nonchallant. “As with all things, my dad got it for me. He set the privacy settings so that it only displays my personal avatar on the leaderboard but we don’t show up on the map—“ She gestured at the leaderboard. Some of the icons and names floated around the animated map of the mall representing people who had placed similar devices next to the leaderboard.

....

> “That and I get free access to the Paradigm Mall cloud,” Bell added. She pulled up her phone and showed Kathleen the app running.
>
> “It says there’s a sale right now at Abel and Böhme!” Kathleen exclaimed and grabbed Bell’s wrist. “Let’s get going, it’s got a timer, and there’s a new wearable management CPU that I want to get. It could be on sale. Let’s go.”